# Cocos2d OpenGL error 0x0506 Error

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Hi I am trying to use the camera with cocos2d. It occurs sometimes and sometimes work perfectly. Here is my code and error that I get:

```
 -(void)playAction{
    CCLOG(@"Take Picture");
    UIImagePickerController *photoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    photoPicker.delegate = self;
    photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    //[self presentViewController:photoPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentModalViewController:photoPicker animated:YES];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)photoPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

    //ConfigureCharacterLayer *asd = [[[ConfigureCharacterLayer alloc]init] autorelease];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[ConfigureCharacterLayer scene:imageView.image]]];

    [imageView release];
    [photoPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This error occurs when I create a picture and press Use Image button which are provided by apple.

```
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCSprite draw] 530
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCSprite draw] 530
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCSprite draw] 530
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCTextureAtlas drawNumberOfQuads:fromIndex:] 573
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCTextureAtlas drawNumberOfQuads:fromIndex:] 573
OpenGL error 0x0506 in -[CCTextureAtlas drawNumberOfQuads:fromIndex:] 573
OpenGL error 0x0502 in -[CCGLView swapBuffers] 283
```

And here is where I load the image:

```
    image3 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 250, 250)];
    image3.layer.zPosition = 200;
    CCLOG(@"Image: %@",capturedImage);
    [image3 setImage:capturedImage];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:image3];
```

Comment: have you found a solution?